# ReactJS + MaterialUI. Property rightIconButton doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I hope, that you can help me with my problem. I can't understand, why property rightIconButton in my example of `<ListItem>` doesn't work (Material UI component).

`<List>`

```
import React from 'react';
import { List } from 'material-ui';
import UsersItem from './UsersItem';

class UsersList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <List>
             {this.props.users.map(user => {
               return <UsersItem key={user.id} deleteUser={this.props.deleteUser} 
                                 user={user}/>
             })}
    </List>;
  }
}

export default UsersList;
```

`<ListItem>`

```
import React from 'react';
import { ListItem, IconButton, Avatar, FontIcon } from 'material-ui';

class UsersItem extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.deleteUser = this.deleteUser.bind(this);
  }

  deleteUser(e) {
    this.props.deleteUser(this.props.user.id);
    e.stopPropagation();
  }


  render() {
    let deleteButton = <IconButton iconClassName="icomoon-icon-delete"
                            onClick={this.deleteUser}>
                        </IconButton>;

    return  <ListItem className="user-item" secondaryText={this.props.user.description}
                      leftAvatar={<Avatar src="./web/images/avatar.jpg" />} 
                      rightIconButton={deleteButton} secondaryTextLines={2}>
            tt { this.props.user.name }
            </ListItem>
  }
}

export default UsersItem;
```

Font icon is correct and if I place it on `<Toolbar>`, it render correct. But it doesn't render in property rightIconButton. I tried SVG icon too from source code on official site of MaterialUI.
Screenshot of result site page (to small reputation for third link) https://github.com/jestonedev/Auction/blob/master/issue.png

What I doing incorrect? Why `rightIconButton` doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

In deleteButton > onClick, you are missing to bind *this* context:

```
onClick={this.deleteUser.bind(this)}
```

This is necessary when using the es6 class syntax.

Comment: I do it in constructor.
Actually, I found a more elegant way without explicit binding
```js
deleteUser = (e) => {
    this.props.deleteUser(this.props.user.id);
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
```
Problem was with documentation. I looked up the source file of ListItem. It doesn't support property `rightIconButton`

Comment: You are right, my bad. Why do you say that rightIconButton is not supported in ListItem? I'm using it right now.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Now ListItem support rightIconButton https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/lists/list-item.jsx#L41

Comment: But in my version of ListItem.jsx missing this property. Already updated =)